# Splice() is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, project

I'm trying to remove a specific element in my frontend once it gets removed from my backend. After successful deletion fetch request I have these lines of code that search and find the specific list & reminder:

```
 let list = List.all.find(l => l.id = parseInt(div.dataset.id))
 let reminder = list.reminders.find(r => r.id = parseInt(div.dataset.id))
 let index = list.reminders.indexOf(reminder)
 list.reminders.splice(index, 1)
```

A list is an object that I store within a static.all inside of a list class. When I set a debugger the last line returns [] which is what I want yet when I remove the div that shows the reminder from the index.html and re-render the reminders, the reminder still shows up, any thoughts on why?

Comment: Are you sure `reminder` is not null?

Comment: Hard to guess why. My guess is you are thinking something is synchronous. Probably need to see more code

Comment: If `splice()` returns `[]` then it didn't remove anything. It returns an array of the elements that were removed.

Comment: You should use `findIndex` instead of `find` followed by `indexOf`.